# Image no debería devolver PositiveInfinity como su DesiredSize

Tags: c#, imagen, wpf

es la primera ves que publico alguna duda pero esta ves agoté mis opciones.

Tengo un dispositivo bluetooth (Plataforma Wii Balance) enlazada a mi ordenador, mediante el uso de una librería logro obtener los datos de medición que la plataforma provee.

Uno de estos datos es un System.Windows.Point, encargado de almacenar coordenadas X e Y, estas coordenadas las muestro mediante un DrawEllipse enlazado a un Image dentro de un ViewBox para graficar todos los puntos que el dispositivo envía.

```
    <Grid x:Name="MyGrid" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Button Content="Button" Margin="0,0,221,10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="Button_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="270"/>

        <Viewbox Grid.Row="0" x:Name="viewBox" Margin="0,0,0,53" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Image x:Name="ImageView" Source="{Binding imageDrawing}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
```

```cs
    //Declaración
    DrawingGroup drawingGroup = new DrawingGroup();

    //Declaración en Main
    this.drawingImage = new DrawingImage(this.drawingGroup);

    public ImageSource imageDrawing
    {
        get
        {
            return this.drawingImage;
        }
    }


    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            using (DrawingContext dc = this.drawingGroup.Open())
            {
                //Si se detecta peso en la plataforma
                if (WiiBoardB.WiimoteState.BalanceBoardState.WeightKg > 0)
                {
                    do
                    {
                        //Dibuja un elipse en los puntos que la plataforma envíe mientras se detecte el peso.
                        this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                        {
                            PosXWii = WiiBoardB.WiimoteState.BalanceBoardState.CenterOfGravity.X;
                            PosYWii = WiiBoardB.WiimoteState.BalanceBoardState.CenterOfGravity.Y;

                            dc.DrawEllipse(System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black, ColorPoint, new System.Windows.Point(PosXWii, (-(PosYWii))), 0.5, 0.5);

                        }));
                    }
                    while (WiiBoardB.WiimoteState.BalanceBoardState.WeightKg > 0);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No se ha detectado peso en la plataforma");
                }

                //Plano Cartesiano
                dc.DrawLine(ColorCross, new System.Windows.Point(-50, 0), new System.Windows.Point(50, 0));
                dc.DrawLine(ColorCross, new System.Windows.Point(0, -50), new System.Windows.Point(0, 50));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ee.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            ImageView.Source = this.imageDrawing;
        }
    }
```

Bien, como pueden ver, el UIElement Image (dentro del contenedor ViewBox) obtiene su Source desde un drawingGroup.

El error se produce al posicionarse incorrectamente en la plataforma (Como solo colocar un pie, o tener una mala postura sobre de ella) y ésta envía coordenadas -Infinity, NaN o Infinity, al graficarlas en

```cs
                    do
                    {
                        this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                        {
                            PosXWii = WiiBoardB.WiimoteState.BalanceBoardState.CenterOfGravity.X;
                            PosYWii = WiiBoardB.WiimoteState.BalanceBoardState.CenterOfGravity.Y;

                            dc.DrawEllipse(System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black, ColorPoint, new System.Windows.Point(PosXWii, (-(PosYWii))), 0.5, 0.5);

                        }));
                    }
                    while (WiiBoardB.WiimoteState.BalanceBoardState.WeightKg > 0);
```

Éste error devuelve en la salida:

> Excepción no controlada del tipo 'System.InvalidOperationException' en PresentationCore.dll
> La invalidación de medición del diseño del elemento 'System.Windows.Controls.Image' no debería devolver PositiveInfinity como su DesiredSize, aunque Infinity se pase como un tamaño disponible.
>
>
> Excepción no controlada: System.InvalidOperationException: La invalidación de medición del diseño del elemento 'System.Windows.Controls.Image' no debería devolver PositiveInfinity como su DesiredSize, aunque Infinity se pase como un tamaño disponible.
>    en System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
>    en System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
>    en System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayoutCallback(Object arg)
>    en System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.InvokeOnRenderCallback.DoWork()
>    en System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()
>    en System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
>    en System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
>    en System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
>    en System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
>    en System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
>    en System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
>    en MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(Object obj)
>    en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>    en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>    en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>    en MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>    en System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
>    en System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
>    en System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
>    en MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
>    en MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
>    en System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
>    en System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
>    en System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
>    en MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
>    en MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
>    en System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
>    en System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
>    en System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
>    en System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
>    en System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
>    en System.Windows.Application.Run()
>    en TestingWiiBoard.App.Main()
> El programa '[752] TestingWiiBoard.exe' terminó con código 0 (0x0).
> El programa '[752] TestingWiiBoard.exe: Seguimiento de programa' terminó con código 0 (0x0).

El cual ya intente evitar con el método Arrange() y Measure() sin resultados positivos.

Al intentar obtener si los valores son Double.IsNan, Infinity, etc, estos siempre devuelven True cuando el procedimiento se hacen incorrectamente, pero la aplicación tiende a cerrar la aplicación debido al crash que este produce al intentar dibujar con estas coordenadas.

¿Cómo puedo evitar que la aplicación crashee y enviar un mensaje de que la postura es incorrecta?, intenté detenerla en el método IsClosing() al invalidar el cierre pero éste nunca se llama, simplemente se cierra directamente sin llamar al método.

OJO: Intenté invalidar la excepción con Try{} pero no lo respeta, igual se cierra la aplicación.

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. La verdad no estoy relacionado con el error que mencionas, pero puedes mirar esta [respuesta en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8078213/4092887) o intenta expandir tu investigación, por ejemplo, busca: `Layout measurement override of element should not return PositiveInfinity as its DesiredSize, even if Infinity is passed in as available size` en Google. Saludos.

Comment: Hola Mauricio mil gracias por tu respuesta y la bienvenida, echaré un ojo al contenido que me compartes. Ya he intentado la busqueda en inglés pero con resultados negativos.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien. Si como dices puedes comprobar que el valor devuelto es `IsNaN` ... que te impide no dibujarlo en esos casos y lanzar un mensaje de error?

Comment: Cuando el valor es NaN se realiza la validación, pero cuando el valor es Infinity, al actualizar el Layout tiende a generar un crash y no logra realizar la validación correctamente.

Comment: No puedes hacer `if ( Double.IsInfinity(WiiBoardB.WiimoteState.BalanceBoardState.CenterOfGravity)){//lanzar mensaje} else {//dibujar en el grafico}`?

Comment: Correcto, no me lo permite, es algo confuso, pero los valores de CenterOfGravity al realizar la comparación NO se muestran como Infinity, más si accedemos a los miembros estáticos se muestran como -Infinity, repito, Double.IsInfinity no lo reconoce, entonces la sentencia pasa como false y lanza el crash. Ahora mismo estoy intentando `protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size)` para sobreescribir el `DesiredSize` en las propiedades del Image

Comment: En palabras más sencillas. Al dibujar la Elipse se crean coordenadas X = Infinity ó Y = Infinity y estas no se pueden graficar en el ViewBox con la clase Image, por ende crashea y lanza este error al intentar actualizar el Layout

`System.InvalidOperationException: La invalidación de medición del diseño del elemento 'System.Windows.Controls.Image' no debería devolver PositiveInfinity como su DesiredSize, aunque Infinity se pase como un tamaño disponible. en System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)`

Comment: He encontrado la solución, algo muy sencillo, ya que no me retornaba True cuando la sentencia era infinita, comparé de ésta manera

`if (PosXWii < float.MaxValue || PosXWii > float.MinValue)
 { 
    //Realiza el proceso
  }` 

Esto devuelve true si el número tiende a +- Infinito (Si sale de los límites).

P.D PosXWii es un Float obtenido de la coordenada X, falta agregar PosYWii (coordenada Y) para evitar la misma interrupción en ese caso.

Dejo la solución por si alguien más tiene un problema similar.

Comment: @BryannLuna me alegra que hayas encontrado una solución. Considera añadir una respuesta en lugar de dejar la solución como un comentario. Pasadas 48h, podrás aceptar tu propia respuesta.

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia y la idea @Pikoh, saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLUCIÓN:

¿Por qué se generaba la excepción `System.InvalidOperationException` en `DesiredSize` como propiedad del control `System.Windows.Controls.Image Image`?

- La función `DrawEllipse(Brushes, Pen, Point, RadioX, RadioY)` intentaba generar una Ellipse con coordenadas +- Infinity, estas coordenadas se extraían de la información que la plataforma (Tabla de balance Wii) envíaba al detectar peso. Al intentar graficarla o dibujarla, hablamos de un Ellipse de tamaño invaluable, por lo cual, la propiedad `Measurament()` es llamada al actualizar el diseño del control `Image` y por ende este tamaño es invaluable por la coordenada/valor `(float)Infinity`.

Código de solución:

1. Se extrae coordenada por coordenada en variables float
2. Estas coordenadas son comparadas en un if o do evaluando si los valores son o no mayores a float.MinValue ó float.MaxValue, de esta
   manera detectamos si el número extraído en las variables es un
   número 'graficable'/'real' o no es infinito
3. Si la sentencia devuelve Infinito, se cancela la operación `DrawEllipse`

```
        if (DataReceived)
        {
            try
            {
                this.drawingGroup.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                {
                    using (DrawingContext dc = drawingGroup.Append())
                    {
                        //Variables float
                        PosXWii = WiiBoardB.WiimoteState.BalanceBoardState.CenterOfGravity.X;
                        PosYWii = WiiBoardB.WiimoteState.BalanceBoardState.CenterOfGravity.Y;

                        do
                        { //Evaluamos si las coordenadas float X son valores dentro de los límites 
                            do 
                            { 
                              //Si se cumplen ambas condiciones, se dibuja el punto o ellipse, caso contrario, no y evitamos llamar al metodo DesiredSize para valores infinitos  
                              DataPoint.Add(new System.Windows.Point(PosXWii, (-(PosYWii))));
                           dc.DrawEllipse(System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black, ColorPoint, new System.Windows.Point(PosXWii, (-(PosYWii))), 0.01, 0.01);
                              ImageView.Source = this.ImgDrawing;
                            } while (PosYWii < float.MaxValue || PosYWii > float.MinValue || float.IsNaN(PosYWii) == false);

                        } while (PosXWii < float.MaxValue || PosXWii > float.MinValue || float.IsNaN(PosXWii) == false);
                    }
                }));
            }
            catch (Exception E)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(E.ToString());
            }
        }
```